# how connecting lnd to btcpayserver

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

status:
lnd on raspberry pi / daily changing ip-address / btcpayserver on vps

problem:
i want to connect my lnd-node to my btcpayserver.
i have to put my url with https in the required field, so i choose a https-domain of mine linked it to a dyndns-server and this one links to my node
i pasted the macaroons as required but the node or the server did connect.
can anybody help?
[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have ssl certificates for your dyndns? can't you use an IP-address instead of dyndns? Can you also access some log files (of lnd to see if there was a connection) and from the BTC Payserver (if they exist). Also did you enable the REST proxy of lnd? (not sure if that has to be done manually in that case can you share the relevant parts of your config file? Don't forget to obfuscate credentials)

Comment: 1. no, the dyndns has no ssl certificate available. this would be really expensive. 2. i can't use an ip-address because the ip address changes nearly every 24 hours. 3. i think there are no logfiles at least, i don't know where to find them. 4 i don't no if the rest proxy of lnd is enabled but it should be